# The question is related to procedures in mysql

Tags: mysql

Create a procedure named 'findAmount' which takes 2 input parameters namely, person_name varchar(100), entry_time datetime and 1 output parameter namely, amount double. This procedure should find the amount for the travel_payment made by the person whose name is passed as an input paramter.

The travel_payment table consists of

`id,travel_card_id,entry_station_id,entry_time,exit_station_id,exit_time,amount`

The travel_card table consists of

```
id,person_name,contact_number,balance
```

.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE findAmount(IN person_name VARCHAR(100),IN entry_time DATETIME,OUT amount DOUBLE)
BEGIN
SELECT amount FROM travel_payment WHERE travel_card_id=(SELECT id FROM travel_card WHERE person_name=person_name);
END;
;

CREATE PROCEDURE findAmount(IN person_name VARCHAR(100),IN entry_time DATETIME,OUT amount DOUBLE)
BEGIN
SELECT amount FROM travel_payment WHERE travel_card_id=(SELECT id FROM travel_card WHERE person_name=person_name);
END;
;
```

I tried using inner join for above query but it fails

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample as tabular ext and the expcted  result

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please change your title releated to your question as everyone can understand and can google.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE findAmount(IN person_name VARCHAR(100), IN entry_time DATETIME, OUT amount DOUBLE)
BEGIN
  SELECT
    p.amount INTO amount
  FROM
    travel_payment p
  INNER JOIN
    travel_card c
    ON p.travel_card_id = c.id
  WHERE c.person_name = person_name;
END$$
```